# Understanding Spring's @Transactional isolation level "Serializable"

Tags: java, spring, transactional, isolation-level

I want to use Spring's @Transactional annotation to prevent concurrency when updating a database record. The isolation level "Serializable" claim to do this, but I want to understand if this indeed covers my use cases and what the full ramifications are of this isolation level. I don't use JPA and we already use optimistic locking (version/timestamp column) for long conversations.

- If my query is a simple `Update table X where id = 123`, will only record 123 be locked while the transaction is ongoing, or the entire table X?
- If it is, then I'm thinking about making ALL my updates, inserts and deletes have this isolation level. I never see any point in allowing concurrent actions on the same record to happen without potentially causing problems. Is this sensical?

Lastly a more complex insert query we have where autoincrement on the id field is not suitable for us (don't ask).

```
@Transactional(Isolation = ????)
public String insertUser(User user){
    Integer nextid = query(select id from table ids where tablename = user);
    query(insert in tabel user using nextId);
    query(update table ids set id = (nextId+1) where tablename = user);
}
```

I want to disallow access to the record that gets the id for the table = "user" until this transaction is completely finished. Which isolation level covers this?

Comment: In Serializable isolation mode databases will not allow data read by your transaction be modified, as read locks will be placed on all read rows so your select for new id should protect other transactions from reading your new insert. Usually there are no table locks unless you’re reading the whole table somewhere.

Comment: Actually serializable isolation just says that the end results of serializable transactions will be exactly as if the transactions were run one after another and not concurrently. How that's implemented in the database is up to it. But you should first read up on the different isolation levels and what they prevent, then when you think you have the hang of that, we can move on to what JPA and Spring do on top of it.

Comment: And no, it's not sensical to make everything serializable. Trying to use common sense to "figure this out" isn't going to work when you don't understand how things work well enough. Maybe start with [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).